# Grouping every 3 items in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, grouping, xslt-1.0

I'm having troubles to figure out a way to group items xslt 1.0.
I have a source xml similar to the one below:

```
<client name="client A">
    <project name = "project A1"/>
    <project name = "project A2"/>
    <project name = "project A3"/>
    <project name = "project A4"/>
</client>
<client name="client B">
    <project name = "project B1"/>
    <project name = "project B2"/>
</client>
<client name="client C">
    <project name = "project C1"/>
    <project name = "project C2"/>
    <project name = "project C3"/>
</client>
```

I'd like to select all projects, sort them and then group every 3 project in one boundle as in the example below:

```
<boundle>
  <project name="project A1">
  <project name="project A2">
  <project name="project A3">
</boundle>
<boundle>
  <project name="project A4">
  <project name="project B1">
  <project name="project B2">
</boundle>
<boundle>
  <project name="project C1">
  <project name="project C2">
  <project name="project C3">
</boundle>
```

Currently to do so I'm using  to open a boundle tag and close it later.
Can you think about any better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No grouping necessary.

```
<xsl:param name="perGroup" select="3" />

<xsl:variable name="allProjects" select="/client/project" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$allProjects" mode="counted" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="project" mode="counted">
  <xsl:if test="position() mod $perGroup = 1">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
    <boundle>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$allProjects[
        position() &gt;= $pos and position() &lt; ($pos + $perGroup)
      ]" />
    </boundle>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I like this solution, since it avoids repetition. I wonder though if it could be simpler, since you now basically loop over all projects, and for every third project, copy the last three projects, instead of copying a project in the first place and just put the boundles around them...

Comment: This cannot be made much simpler. You could do `<xsl:apply-templates select="$allProjects[position() mod 3 = 1]" ...` and remove the `<xsl:if>` in exchange, but in terms of processing this is pretty much the same thing. Also, the way I did it, the `<project>` template is self-contained. Regarding the potential use of an XSL key: since there is no consecutive range of projects, `position() mod x` will not produce the desired results. Apart from that, the above is parameterized, an XSL key would have to be hard-coded.

Comment: is right. In making my solution work (now deleted) it gets hopelessly complex dealing with different edge cases where the 2nd or 3rd project in a bundle moves into the next, or next plus one client nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the following link http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/ which helped me figuring out how to group various number of elements into some categories based on the contents in the XML document.

Comment: You shouldn't just give a link to another site as an answer, since the site may go out of date in the future. Instead, click the "edit" link on this answer and include the essential parts of the solution from that page here. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259